# Breakpoint in GDB for specific object

Tags: c++, gdb, this, breakpoints

I need to check where destructor of some specific object is called from.
Let's say it is std::string at 0x9b993e4.
I tried to execute following:

```
b std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string if (this==0x9b993e4)
```

But GDB says "No symbol "this" in current context."
I also tried

```
b std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string if (std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::this==0x9b993e4)
```

GDB looks like set breakpoint, but when I run, it stops and writes

```
Error in testing breakpoint condition:
There is no field named this
```

Can anyone tell me how to break in destructor of specific object?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have debuginfo for libstdc++ installed? gdb isn't likely to know any argument names unless it has debuginfo. If you place a breakpoint at `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string`, run to it, and then do `info args`, is anything displayed?

Comment: Hm, you are right, Mark. Actually I didn't have any debug information about libstdc++. Then I installed some .deb file containing debug symbols. When gdb loads symbols for this lib I have message:
    Reading symbols from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19...done.
    done.
SO looks like symbols are available, but "info args" in string destructor causes message "No symbol table info available"

Comment: ""info shared" also tells that symbols are available... Any ideas what I miss?

Comment: I'll try to reproduce. What distribution are you using, and what .deb file with debuginfo did you install? (If you're running Debian/Ubuntu/Mint, what does `dpkg -f packagename.deb  package version architecture` say?)

Comment: Hi @MarkPlotnick. Actually I'm not very experienced in Linux/Ubuntu, so probably I will provide not what you are asking...
Here is output of "uname -a" - "Linux alex-XubuntuVM 3.13.0-65-generic #105-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 21 18:51:54 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux"
I downloaded and installed libstdc++6-4.8-dbg_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04_i386.deb.
Here is output of dpkg:
Package: libstdc++6-4.8-dbg
Version: 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04
Architecture: i386

Comment: I get the results you mention on 32-bit xubuntu 14.04 the first time the breakpoint for `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string` is hit. It stops at the PLT entry. But every breakpoint after that stops at the real entry for the string destructor, and `this` is accessible. Can you confirm that?

Comment: Hi @MarkPlotnick. In my case I have mix of global static strings and strings allocated on heap during creation of some objects. Yes, I noticed that sometimes "this" may be available, sometimes - not. In case of global static objects, as I remember, it was never available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find any better way than use registers.
So, on x86 you can check EAX, on ARM, probably, R0.

```
b ClassName::~ClassName if ($eax==<object_address>)
```

This solution doesn't work for some global static objects in my case.

Answer (score 0):

```
break std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()
```

Comment: This will break on destructor of every string in project, which is not acceptable.
Question was about breaking in destructor of specific object.